# How to reboot Ubuntu the Magic SysRQ way using a Dell's E5450 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell

I have a Dell Latitude E5450 and I don't know how to reboot it the Magic SysRQ way.

On a default keyboard, I hold both <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s-abf (print)</kbd> and press the following sequence:

<kbd>R</kbd>
<kbd>E</kbd>
<kbd>I</kbd>
<kbd>S</kbd>
<kbd>U</kbd>
<kbd>B</kbd>

What's the eqivalent way here?

Answer (score 0):

On a different localisation the keyboard layout lets us access some function with an additional modifier key <kbd>Fn</kbd> only.

For the German layout of the Dell E5450 the PrtScrn button is realised by <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ende</kbd>. You should be able to access the magic SysRQ keys by:

<kbd>Strg</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>[**Fn**](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN295368/EN)</kbd><kbd>Ende</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>